# iOS 5 UINavigationBar removing subviews ( image subview) removes navigation bar

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

In my application that works fine on iOS 4 navigationBar dissappeared starting iOS 5. Here is what I figured caused issue: I was removing subviews in RootViewController viewWillAppear method:

```
for(UIView* view in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews)
    {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) 
        {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
        {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
```

I was doing this because Second view controller that I push onto navigation controller add's image and label to navigation bar which I have to remove when view is popped. In iOS 5 the above code removes navigationBar. How to fix this or right way of doing it to support both iOS4 and iOS 5 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

setTag for those image and uilabel then removing it from code above did the trick.

```
for(UIView* view in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews)
{
   if(view.tag == 9 || view.tag == 99)
   {
      [view removeFromSuperview];
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this will technically work, but your code becomes significantly less understandable if you or someone else needed to come back to it later. You run the risk of not being able to effectively read and keep track of what your code is doing. At the very least make those tags constants to help see what you are removing.

Comment: You could simply remove the subview using the below code

[(UILabel *)[self.navigationController.navigationBar viewWithTag:yourViewTag] removeFromSuperview];

Answer (score 0):

You could make your added views subclasses of their respective UIKit classes and check against those specific subclasses. Really though, to have the clearest, most readable code, you should subclass the navigation controller and navigation bar to allow for a custom image and label to be drawn such that you could simply set the background image and foreground label to nil. It would take a little time to put together, but the end result would be much more extendable.