# iOS navigation bar subview reappear after removing

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

I am adding a view to the navigation bar

```
UIView *mySubView = [UIView alloc] initwithFrame:frame];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:mySubView];
```

I want to remove the view before pushing to secondviewController.

```
[mySubView removeFromSuperView];
```

When App launch first time it did not remove the view, so view also visible on secondview navigation bar

I searched and tried many approaches, but didn't find any solution.

Comment: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747546/ios-5-uinavigationbar-removing-subviews-image-subview-removes-navigation-bar?rq=1**

Check this it will help you

Comment: I have tried this approach but it is not working.

Comment: I assume that your `[mySubView removeFromSuperView];` call must be written in some other method, which definitely cannot access `mySubView` as it's a local variable. Hence, Compile time error.

Comment: I able to fix this issue by placing code before I call push methos
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign a tag to you mysubview like

```
UIView *mySubView = [UIView alloc] initwithFrame:frame];
mySubView.tag =1;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:mySubView];
```

Then add this line when you push to secondViewController.

```
[[self.navigationController.navigationBar viewWithTag:1] removeFromSuperview];
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: May I know the reason of downvote this answer whoever has downvoted this?

Answer (score 2):

Add a value to the **tag** property of the views you want to remove and check for it before removing the the subview, for example, assuming that you add a non-zero value to your subviews:

```
 for (UIView *view in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews) {
if (view.tag != 0) {
    [view removeFromSuperview];
     }
}
```

**Try this it will help !!!!**

Comment: perfect ans to remove subview from navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

Do following for the `ViewController` in which you are having subView for `NavigationBar`

in `.h`

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *mySubView;
```

in `.m`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    //Your Existing Code + following 2 lines
    self.mySubView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:yourFrame];
    self.mySubView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    //Your Existing Code + following 1 line
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:self.mySubView];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    //Your Existing Code + following 1 line
    [self.mySubView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

And you are good to go. Tried and tested.

Answer (score 0):

```
  -(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated    
      {
        [self.mySubView removeFromSuperview];
      //[_mySubView removeFromSuperview];

    }
```

Comment: Adds some more explanation. It's not really sufficent like this